# Sylow subgroups of the restricted Burnside group $\mathrm{RB}(d,n)$?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\RB{RB}$What is known about the Sylow subgroups of the [restricted Burnside groups $\RB(d,n)$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Restricted_Burnside_group) ?

I am looking for a reference.

In fact my question is slightly more general. Recall that, category-theoretically,
a restricted Burnside group $\RB(d,n)$
is the coproduct (or free product) of $d$ cyclic groups $C_n$
in the subcategory $\mathit{FinGroups} \bmod n$ of finite groups with each element of order dividing $n$.
Let us denote this coproduct by $(C_n * .. * C_n) \bmod n $.

More generally, I am interested in the structure of Sylow subgroups of groups $A * P \bmod n$ where $P$ is a $p$-group, and order of $A$ is prime to $p$.

Note that many finite groups can be generated by two elements of order $2$ and $3$,
and this means that $C_2 * C_3 \bmod n $ is rather large and complicated.